# Reorganize d3 cluster-force layout based on dynamic radii

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I initialize my cluster force diagram with even sized radii for every circle. The radii of the circles get updated when the user presses a button on my site. I would like the clusters to reorganize with the larger nodes in the center. Right now I can get the radii to change but they don't reorganize and the nodes often overlap. I've tried messing with charge and gravity. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are some images to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Initialized nodes:
[image]

After radii are changed:
[image]

More or less the behavior I'd like to see:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```
<script>

var width = document.getElementById("d3_ex").clientWidth,
    height = 600
    padding = 3, // separation between same-color circles
    clusterPadding = 6, // separation between different-color circles
    maxRadius = 5;


var n = {{items[0].collection_size}}, // total number of circles
    m = {{items[0].n_clusters}}, // number of distinct clusters
    data = {{items[0].data|safe}},
    heroNode = {{items[0].hero_id}};

var color = d3.scale.category10()
    .domain(d3.range(m));

// The largest node for each cluster.
var clusters = new Array(m);

var nodes = data.map(function(d) {
  var i = d.cluster,
      r = d.radius * maxRadius + 1,
      t = d.art_title,
      id = d.id_,
      d = {"cluster": i, "radius": r, "id_":id};
  if (!clusters[i] || (r > clusters[i].radius)) clusters[i] = d;
  return d;
});

var svg = d3.select("#d3_ex").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(nodes)
        .size([width, height])
        .gravity(0.02)
        .charge(function(d, i) {-Math.pow(data[i].radius, 2.0) / 8} )
        .on("tick", tick);

    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
        .attr("id_", function(d) {return d.id_; })
        .attr("url", function(d) {return d.url; })
        .call(force.start)
        .call(force.drag);

function updateData(json) {
      var data = json['0']['data']

      var nodes = data.map(function(d) {
        var i = d.cluster,
            r = d.radius + 1,
            t = d.art_title,
            id = d.id_,
            u = d.url,
            p = d.retail_price,
            m = d.medium,
            w = d.art_width,
            h = d.art_height,
            d = {"cluster": i, "radius": r, "id_":id};
        if (!clusters[i] || (r > clusters[i].radius)) clusters[i] = d;
        return d;
      });

      var force = d3.layout.force()
          .nodes(nodes)
          .size([width, height])
          .gravity(0.05)
          .charge(function(d, i) {-Math.pow(data[i].radius, 2.0) / 8} )
          .on("tick", tick);

      circles
          .transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .attr('r', function(d, i) {return data[i].radius * maxRadius})
          .call(force.start)
          .call(force.drag);
}

$("#like_button").click(function() {
  var art_id = this.getAttribute("data-art")
  console.log('hi')
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/likes/" + art_id,
      success: function(results) {
          updateData(results.items)
          console.log('success')
      }
  })
})

function tick(e) {
  circles
      .each(cluster(10 * e.alpha * e.alpha))
      .each(collide(.5))
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

// Move d to be adjacent to the cluster node.
function cluster(alpha) {
  return function(d) {
    var cluster = clusters[d.cluster];
    if (cluster === d) return;
    var x = d.x - cluster.x,
        y = d.y - cluster.y,
        l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
        r = d.radius + cluster.radius;
    if (l != r) {
      l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
      d.x -= x *= l;
      d.y -= y *= l;
      cluster.x += x;
      cluster.y += y;
    }
  };
}

// Resolves collisions between d and all other circles.
function collide(alpha) {
  var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
  return function(d) {
    var r = d.radius + maxRadius + Math.max(padding, clusterPadding),
        nx1 = d.x - r,
        nx2 = d.x + r,
        ny1 = d.y - r,
        ny2 = d.y + r;
    quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
            y = d.y - quad.point.y,
            l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
            r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.cluster === quad.point.cluster ? padding : clusterPadding);
        if (l < r) {
          l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
          d.x -= x *= l;
          d.y -= y *= l;
          quad.point.x += x;
          quad.point.y += y;
        }
      }
      return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
    });
  };
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle ?

Comment: I'm so new to javascript and d3 I don't even know what that is. I'm sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: Dragon_Slayer means to put a minimum example showing the problem in https://jsfiddle.net/ and posting the saved link here so that others can try to play around with the code and try to help debug it.